# Good data structure or database to represent objects and transitions between objects?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, nosql, graph-algorithm

I'm having trouble choosing a data structure to use to help identify resources and transitions between resources.  After the graph is defined, I'd like to run analysis on the transformation between resources to determine what inputs could yield what outputs.

For example, we could take traditional currency for example:

- Dollar ->  3:2 -> Euros
- Euros -> 2:3 -> Dollar
- Euros -> 1:100 -> Yen
- Yen -> 95:1 -> Euro
- Yen -> 50:1 -> T-shirt
- Dollar -> 2:1 -> Candy Bar

The typical use case would be to take some starting resources, such 5 USD and 100 Japan Yen, and determine what these could be transformed into: how many candy bars? how any tshirts? The graph would be much more complicated through with hundreds of resources each with potentially dozens of transitions to other resources.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Can't you define a transition between any two resources? That would essentially make that a clique. Or do you want something more compact, or have some limitations on possible transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a problem for a standard graph.

Let each resource be a node and connect 2 nodes if there's a transition between them, with the edge weight being the transition ratio.

These edges will probably need to be directed, and, if the transitions are inverses, have 2 edges, one in either direction. Alternatively, if the transitions are inverses, you can have an undirected graph and define the edge weight as the transition ratio from the 'smallest' node to the 'largest' (you'll need to have some possibly arbitrary ordering of node). By "transitions are inverses" I mean, if you go from any resource to any other resource, you can also go back again, and, if you do so, you get back the same amount as you originally started with (although, this doesn't appear to hold from the example).

Then you'll probably have to use [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (or similar) to determine getting from one resource to another.

In terms of SQL, a possible structure is as follows:

```
Resource
  ID, ...

Transition
  ResourceID1, ResourceID2, Cost
```